# Unable to start webpack-dev-server

Tags: npm, webpack-dev-server

I am attempting to do a React tutorial, and although I have downloaded files from the instructor, I am unable to start the web-dev-server on my laptop.  I can, however, get it to work on my desktop computer.  I will need to be able to work on my laptop, though, so I would appreciate any help in figuring out what's wrong.  I have tried deleting and re-installing the the node_modules folder (many times), as well as deleting just the webpack-dev-server folder and re-installing that.  As far as I can tell no other program is using the same port (8080).

Here is the error log I get:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.0
3 info using node@v8.11.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle github-battle@1.0.0~prestart: github-battle@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle github-battle@1.0.0~start: github-battle@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle github-battle@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle github-battle@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/eleerogers/Downloads/react-fundamentals-first-component/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle github-battle@1.0.0~start: CWD: /Users/eleerogers/Downloads/react-fundamentals-first-component
10 silly lifecycle github-battle@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'webpack-dev-server --open' ]
11 silly lifecycle github-battle@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle github-battle@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: github-battle@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --open`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:304:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid github-battle@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/eleerogers/Downloads/react-fundamentals-first-component
16 verbose Darwin 17.7.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v8.11.3
19 verbose npm  v6.4.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error github-battle@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --open`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the github-battle@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here is the webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html'
    })
  ],
  mode: "development"
};
```

And here is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "github-battle",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Project for TylerMcGinnis.com's fundamental course.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open"
  },
  "author": "Tyler McGinnis",
  "license": "MIT",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "env",
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0-alpha.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.5"
  }
}
```

Although, as I said, it works on my desktop, so I don't think it's anything wrong with those... something is going on with my laptop.  It is a new Macbook Air. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -2):

npm clean cache

then

npm install

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I tried this ("npm cache clean --force", followed by "npm install" ... also tried "sudo npm cache clean -f" followed by "sudo npm install npm@latest -g"), but I'm still getting the same error message.  Thanks for the suggestion though!